# Compute the expected number of typos found as a function of the arrival rate $\lambda$

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, poisson-process

> A copy editor reads a $200$-page manuscript, finding $108$ typos. Suppose that the author's typos follow a Poisson process with some unknown rate $\lambda$ per page, while from long experience we know that the copyeditor finds $90\%$ of the mistakes that are there.
>
> > **(a)** Compute the expected number of typos found as a function of the arrival rate $\lambda$.
> >
> > **(b)** Use the answer to **(a)**  to find an estimate of $\lambda$ and the number of undiscovered typos.

Would appreciate some sort of push in the right direction. For part **(a)**, I know the Expected value of a poisson is just it's rate (in this case $\lambda$). But not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part (a): The mean number of typos found in $200$ pages will be $0.9\lambda . 200 =180\lambda$.

Part (b): We need to find a reasonable value for $\lambda$ given that an observation of a Poisson r.v. with parameter $180\lambda$ equals $108$. This gives us $\lambda = 0.6$ errors per page. This gives us an expected number of $200\lambda =120$ typos actually there, of which $12$ haven’t been found yet.

Comment: He did say he just wanted a push, not the answer…